How many lags are needed for studying the autocorrelation of a signal given its bandwidth and sampling frequency?
Say that I have a sequence of sensor readings. Assume that the sampling frequency of the sensor is $F_s = 50\, Hz$. Assume that I picked $N = 3500$ samples and that they are passed through a 1st order low-pass filter with a cutoff frequency of $F_c= 10\, Hz$.
Next, I want to study the auto-correlation of the resulting signal and I have the problem on how many lags to select and how to interpret the results.
My gut feeling suggests me to take $n_{lags} = kF_s/F_c$ and $k>2$ to preserve the Shannon-Nyquist criteria. For example, one could take $k=20$. With the numerical values of above I would consider $100$ lags.
Moreover, in my understanding, for all the lags  in the interval from $-F_s/F_c$ to $F_s/F_c$ I would expect a high level of auto-correlation given that the sensor is sampled very fast and therefore two consecutive measurements are most likely correlated. A meaningful analysis would consider only auto-correlation values outside such such a region, i.e. for lags greater than $F_s/F_c$ and smaller than $-F_s/F_c$, which, with the numerical values of above, it means to ignore autocorrelation values in the lags $ -5, -4, \dots 0, \dots, 4, 5$. Does it make sense?
Would down-sampling the signal to $20-25\,Hz$ before computing the autocorrelation be a solution?
Would computing the auto-correlation with the signal as-is and then pick only the auto-correlation values at lags located multiple of $F_s/F_c$ for autocorrelation analysis be wound (and equivalent to the first proposed solution)?
Or would just picking a larger number of lags by giving few importance on what happens around lag = 0 be a solution?

I think you are asking decent questions but probably have some wrong intuition. If anything, you would want to keep only the central lags because they have undergone more averaging and are likely to be better estimates of the true ACS. Consecutive measurements being correlated means there is some information there, and not just noise. Outside of a reasonable length window, if your signal is sufficiently noisy, the ACS will trend towards zero pretty quickly.

Another thing that should probably be considered, that my guess would be more important, is the filter length. Assuming an FIR filter, your correlation structure would be something like $h^{T}\mathbf{R}h$, where $\mathbf{R}$ is the correlation matrix. So, the underlying structure of the signal is being modified by the filter out to the length of the filter.

In reality I want to assess how “white” is my overall signal after sampling and filtering. If I limit to say 4 lags, then would have high correlation, even if the equivalent non-oversampled signal is not autocorrelated. I would need more lags given the signal bandwidth to see repetitive patterns. Regarding the filter I assume a IIR. I am interested in the autocorrelation of the signal picked at the out of the filter.

In that case I’d probably start by seeing how quickly the ACS decays to zero rather than analyzing only high lag components since the ACS of pure white noise is a delta, and I’d use a biased ACS estimate. You could take a gradient of the ACS and see at what point the gradient approaches 0. That might give some good results. Unless I’m not understanding your goals correctly.

I think you got it right. I am thinking that looking at the acs gradient tells you when the strong auto-correlation due to over-sampling ends, but from that point you should see the actual value of the acf, correct? In-fact you can have zero gradient over several lags that measure all e.g. 0.8 acf values… no?

What do you mean by "you should see the actual value of the acf"? And, I don't think it would be possible to have an acf with zero gradient except if it were all zeros. The power spectral density is the Fourier transform of the acf. The Fourier transform of a rectangular function would be a sinc function, so anything rectangular in nature would require a negative value in its Fourier transform. However, the PSD is strictly non-negative, which would violate that requirement.

I meant that the value of a function is different than the value of its derivative at the same point. The gradient slope abrupt change won't say anything about the overall signal auto-correlation without the actual value of the AFC at that point. I can experience an abrupt change in a lag where ACF is 0.8 or an abrupt change when the ACF is 0.01. Regarding the "flatness" of the AFC you can think to a almost constant signal. Not sure how much precision I had to express when I claimed "all e.g. 0.8 acf values". However, I don't that kind of discussion would lead anywhere.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I use autocorrelation or something very similar for pitch detection.  More specifically, to estimate or determine the period length of a quasi-periodic audio signal (like a musical note).  The reciprocal of the period is the fundamental frequency of the quasi-periodic signal and the base-2 logarithm of the fundamental frequency is the pitch (measured in octaves, relative to some reference pitch like A-440 or middle C or MIDI note 0).
The number of lags that I need is some number slightly more than the longest period I ever expect to see.  That longest period corresponds to the lowest-pitched note.
So for a guitar, the lowest note is E at 82.41 Hz.  That's a period of 12.13 ms.  Suppose the sample rate is 48 kHz, that's 0.02 ms per sample period.  Then the note period is about 582.5 samples.  So I would need about 600 lags to my autocorrelation to be able to estimate a pitch of a note as low as I would ever get for a guitar.  No need to go lower unless the guitar has a wang-bar on it.
Now computing the autocorrelation for 600 lags is a fuckuva lotta processing, especially for real time.  So then you gotta figger out how to cut some corners, which means you need to figure out which corners to cut.  I don't compute the autocorrelation for every single lag, just for some of them.

Fine. But my question mapped to your example would be more: say that I have 5 notes in a row. Is there any note repeated? About the computational power I don’t have real-time constraints, computations are done offline. But good point.
